# Facebook ,google , and twitter official sign in in button on same row and well design

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

[image]Dears,
i am trying to implement social media sign up in my oracle apex  login page, so i am using now the JavaScript APIs for every social media app. My problem is the **design** the buttons not appear on nice way .. i would like to make all of theme in the same row and on same width and height

Progress can be seen below

```
<div class="g-signin2" onclick="gmailLogin()" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-width="200" data-height="30" data-longtitle="false"></div>
</br> 
<div id="fb-root" ></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="my link></script><div class="fb-login-button fb_iframe_widget" data-width="" onlogin="facebookLogin()" data-size="medium" data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

Comment: Please edit the post to include your code, it's hard to give you a solution without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: my code is a part of big oracle apex html page... but i am using the official buttons like the fowling    <div   class="g-signin2"  onclick="gmailLogin()" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-width="200" data-height="30" data-longtitle="false"></div></br>
<div id="fb-root"  ></div><script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="my link></script><div class="fb-login-button fb_iframe_widget" data-width="" onlogin="facebookLogin()" data-size="medium"  data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>

Comment: Are you able to share the CSS properties of `g-signin2` and `fb-root` if there's any?

Comment: these are from API provider i think not from my side

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="g-signin2" onclick="gmailLogin()" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-width="200" data-height="30" data-longtitle="false"></div>
</br> 
<div id="fb-root" ></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="my link></script><div class="fb-login-button fb_iframe_widget" data-width="" onlogin="facebookLogin()" data-size="medium" data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

Change the code as below

```
<div class="" style="width:100%">
    <div style= "width:100%" class="g-signin2" onclick="gmailLogin()" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-width="200" data-height="30"
        data-longtitle="false">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="" style="width:100%">
    <div style="width:100%" id="fb-root"></div>
</div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="my link></script><div class=" fb-login-button fb_iframe_widget"
    data-width="" onlogin="facebookLogin()" data-size="medium" data-button-type="continue_with"
    data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false">
```

Comment: i am not good in css and html design.. now the functionality is working fine what i need a full design method for inline buttons and also the shape of buttons

Comment: What kind of shape changes are you looking for?

Comment: There is no any design. but i think if they become as square beside each other .. note that twitter button also will be added .
thank you